# Number pad above tool bar

Tags: iphone, uiview, uitabbarcontroller

I want to place a number pad for entering digits above a tab bar (like the builtin dialer in MobilePhone.app).

The default behavior is to overlay the tab bar, which not only looks ugly, but also makes it impossible to leave the page. Is it possible (and allowed) to move the keyboard somehow? Or do I need to roll my own keypad control?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the record, I didn't find a way to do it, and after lots of research I ended up believing that either

- It is not possible
- It is possible, but requires some black magic using the view hierarchy, which Apple probably woudln't like anyway

Comment: If you have a better answer, feel free to add it and I will make it the accepted answer ...